# Метод не меняет значение объекта в классе

Tags: c++, классы, объекты, методы, вектор

Я только недавно начал проходить ООП в академии и не могу разобраться с проблемой (сразу извиняюсь за польский язык):
Почему метод UstawStaroste в классе Dziekanat не меняет значение объектов класса Student (grupa.bylyStarosta и grupa.Starosta) в классе Grupa?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long Randomize()
{
    unsigned long long randnumber = 0;
    int digits[20];

    for (int i = 19; i >= 1; i--)
    {
      digits[i]=rand()%10;
    }
    for(int i=19; i>=1; i--)
    {
       unsigned long long power = pow(10, i-1);

        if (power%2 != 0 && power != 1)     //eliminates "bug" (which comes from long long power is not a float))
            power++;

        randnumber += power * digits[i];
    }
return randnumber;
}

class Student {
public:

    string imie;
    string nazwisko;
    int nrNaLiscieWgrupie;
    int nrIndeksu;
    long long int PESEL;

    void PrzedstawSie () {
        cout<< imie << " " << nazwisko << " " << nrNaLiscieWgrupie << " " << nrIndeksu << " " << PESEL << endl;
    }

    Student(string imie, string nazwisko, int nrNaLiscieWgrupie, int nrIndeksu, long long int PESEL)
    {
        this->imie = imie;
        this->nazwisko = nazwisko;
        this->nrNaLiscieWgrupie = nrNaLiscieWgrupie;
        this->nrIndeksu = nrIndeksu;
        this->PESEL = PESEL;
    }
    
    Student()
    {
    }

};

class Grupa {
public:
    
    vector<Student> studenci;
    Student starosta;
    Student bylyStarosta;
    
    string imie;
    string nazwisko;
    int nrNaLiscieWgrupie;
    int nrIndeksu;
    long long int PESEL;
    
    
    void Wypisz () {
        for (std::vector<Student>::size_type i=0; i < studenci.size(); i++)
        {
            studenci.at(i).PrzedstawSie();
        }
        cout << "Obecny starosta = ";
        starosta.PrzedstawSie();
        cout << "Poprzedni starosta = ";
        bylyStarosta.PrzedstawSie();
    }
    
    void Wypisz (int nrIndeksu)
        {
            for (std::vector<Student>::size_type i=0; i < studenci.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (studenci.at(i).nrIndeksu == nrIndeksu)
                    {
                        studenci.at(i).PrzedstawSie();
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        
    void WypiszPoNrWgrupie (int nrNaLiscieWgrupie)
    {
        for (std::vector<Student>::size_type i=0; i < studenci.size(); i++)
            {
                if (studenci.at(i).nrNaLiscieWgrupie == nrNaLiscieWgrupie)
                {
                    studenci.at(i).PrzedstawSie();
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    
    void DodajStudenta ()
    {       
            cout << "Podaj dane: " << endl;
            cout << "Imie   ";
            cin >> imie;
            cout << endl << "Nazwisko   ";
            cin >> nazwisko;
            cout << endl << "Numer na liscie w grupie   ";
            cin >> nrNaLiscieWgrupie;
            cout << endl << "Numer Indeksu   ";
            cin >> nrIndeksu;
            PESEL = Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000;
            cout << endl;
            studenci.push_back(Student(imie, nazwisko, nrNaLiscieWgrupie, nrIndeksu, PESEL));
    }
    
    void UsunStudenta (int nrIndeksu)
    {
        for (std::vector<Student>::size_type i=0; i < studenci.size(); i++)
            {
                if (studenci.at(i).nrIndeksu == nrIndeksu)
                {
                    studenci.erase(studenci.begin() + i);
                    break;
                }   
            }
    }
    
        Grupa(Student starosta, Student bylyStarosta)
    {
        this->starosta = starosta;
        this->bylyStarosta = bylyStarosta;
    }
    
};

class Dziekanat {
public:
    void UstawStaroste (Grupa grupa, int nrIndeksu)
    {
        for (std::vector<Student>::size_type i=0; i < grupa.studenci.size(); i++)
            {
                if (grupa.studenci.at(i).nrIndeksu == nrIndeksu)
                {
                    //grupa.studenci.at(i).PrzedstawSie();
                    grupa.bylyStarosta = grupa.starosta;
                    grupa.starosta = grupa.studenci.at(i);  
                    break;
                }
            }   
    }
};


/* MENU */
void menu()
{
    cout<<"0.Pokaz Menu\n";
    cout<<"1.Pokaz wszystkich studentow grupy\n";
    cout<<"2.Wyszukaj studenta wedlug numeru Indeksu\n";
    cout<<"3.Wyszukaj studenta wedlug numer na liscie grupy\n";
    cout<<"4.Dodaj studenta do grupy\n";
    cout<<"5.Usun studenta z grupy\n";
    cout<<"6.Ustawic nowego staroste\n";
    cout<<"-1.Zakoncz\n";

}

int main ()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    
    Dziekanat dziekanat;
    vector<Grupa> grupy;
    
    Student student1 = Student ("Albert", "Surikowski", 1, 81510, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student2 = Student ("Grzegorz", "Kowalski", 2, 81520, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student3 = Student ("Michal", "Lewandowski", 3, 81511, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student4 = Student ("Magdalena", "Piliecka", 4, 81523, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student5 = Student ("Wiktor", "Bachman", 5, 81536, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student6 = Student ("Basia", "Leopold", 6, 81547, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student7 = Student ("Alexander", "Mirokowski", 7, 81512, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student8 = Student ("Miroslaw", "Ptaszek", 8, 81555, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student9 = Student ("Natalia", "Rybinska", 9, 81559, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student10 = Student ("Julia", "Zielinska", 10, 81581, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student11 = Student ("Michal", "Matroskin", 11, 81526, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student12 = Student ("Dawid", "Szarikow", 12, 81591, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student13 = Student ("Jakub", "Kurczak", 13, 81566, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student14 = Student ("Bartosz", "Rybak", 14, 81573, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student15 = Student ("Mateusz", "Student", 15, 81519, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student16 = Student ("Rafal", "Muzyk", 16, 81505, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000); 
    Student student17 = Student ("Agnieszka", "Boltun", 1, 81518, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);
    Student student18 = Student ("Maciej", "Kozlik", 1, 81502, Randomize()%10000000000+90000000000);        
    
    Grupa grupa1 (student1, student1);
    
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student1);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student2);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student3);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student4);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student5);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student6);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student7);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student8);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student9);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student10);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student11);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student12);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student13);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student14);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student15);
    grupa1.studenci.push_back(student16);
    
    grupy.push_back(grupa1);       
    
    Grupa grupa2 (student17, student17);
    
    grupa2.studenci.push_back(student17);
    
    grupy.push_back(grupa2);
    
    Grupa grupa3 (student18, student18);
    
    grupa3.studenci.push_back(student18);   
    
    grupy.push_back(grupa3);

    int nr = 0;

    cout<< "Grupa 1   Grupa 2   Grupa 3 \n \n";
    cout<<"Podaj nr grupy z ktorej chcesz pracowac: ";
    cin >> nr;
    nr--;
    
    int symbol = 0;
    
    int nrIndeksu;
    int nrNaLiscieWgrupie;

    menu();
    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"\nPodaj polecenie(0-6;-1 koniec): ";
        cin >> symbol;
        cout<<endl;

        if (symbol == -1)
            break;
        switch(symbol)
        {

        case 0:
            menu();
            break;

        case 1:
            grupy[nr].Wypisz();
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Wprowadz numer indeksu: ";
            cin >> nrIndeksu;
            cout << endl;
            grupy[nr].Wypisz(nrIndeksu);
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "Wprowadz numer na liscie w grupie: ";
            cin >> nrNaLiscieWgrupie;
            cout << endl;
            grupy[nr].WypiszPoNrWgrupie(nrNaLiscieWgrupie);
            break;

        case 4:
            grupy[nr].DodajStudenta();
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "Wprowadz numer indeksu: ";
            cin >> nrIndeksu;
            cout << endl;
            grupy[nr].UsunStudenta(nrIndeksu);
            break;

        case 6:
            cout << "Wprowadz numer indeksu: ";
            cin >> nrIndeksu;
            cout << endl;
            dziekanat.UstawStaroste(grupy[nr], nrIndeksu);
            break;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: плюс нарушен инвариант  объектов и,  много лишнего

Comment: Может поясните?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Он меняет. Именно там, где вы просите -

```
void UstawStaroste (Grupa grupa, int nrIndeksu)
```

в переданной по значению (а значит, скопированной) `grupa`. Все, что вы с ней делаете, за пределы функции не выходит.

Наверное, вы просто забыли `&`?

```
void UstawStaroste (Grupa& grupa, int nrIndeksu)
```

Comment: Да, всё верно. Амперсанд всё исправил. Спасибо)